# How to Speed up execution time of DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

I have developed an application in ASP.Net MVC 4.5 framework which is hosted on Application server. I am using two DB Server, One is for Development and another one is for production.

Whenever I have linked my application to Production DB Server, it uploads file very slowly, and when I have linked my application to Development DB Server it uploads file quickly.

Note : Application is hosted on different server.

So, Please guys suggest me, what I have to do.

Comment: Find out where the slowness is.  It could be the sql, profile/trace it.  It could be the network - are your database servers in the same location? It could be the application code - is anything else running at the same time in production that isn't in development?

Comment: Please include your definition of "upload" and explain what you've tried. You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You either have a network problem or the production server is slow.

Since your local machine's web application can reach the database I guess the database I guess you can upload files too. Try to copy a similar file through Windows Explorer and decide if it is fast or not. If it is slow, you know more.

Get hold of an ops s/he can help you with sniffing the network because being two at a problem is nicer and ofter smarter than sitting in your own chamber.

If the network is fast. Use the same ops to find out the load on the database, if it is using to much cpu/memory.

Comment: Debugging hints generally aren't considered to be answers. We don't know what's the problem here, so we can go into troubleshooting, profiling and whatnot, but for an answer like that to be complete, you'd need an entire book.